# Django web site URLS gets "?next=" randomly after deployed to heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

After deploying django app on heroku the url after every form submission or link in site been press resulting with "?next=" inserts into the URL address, I don't understand from where it comes and why heroku keep inserting them in a random way, running the application locally just working perfectly.

I've deleted the application from heroku and upload it again, the fault persists.

There's no http errors what so ever. If I keep submitting the form eventually will works.

For example: pressing the log button in the django admin console results with this URL: https://appname.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/login/admin/, hitting it quite a bit will finally make it work with the correct url display: https://mishnayot.herokuapp.com/admin/.

Switching from heroku postgres to AWS RDS postgres didn't help.

Help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When a user hits a page requiring authentication, they get redirected to the login URL with a `?next=` indicating the page they were trying to access.  This way, after they've logged in, they'll get the page they intended to access.

In your case, it seems like `/admin/login/admin/` requires a login and the login is actually at `/admin/login/`.  I'm guessing you have a bad link to `/admin/login/admin/` somewhere when you intended to just have `/admin/login/`?

Comment: i didn't set a login required over the login view. the issue goes also for all the other links, some of them dont even required authentication

Comment: Is `/admin/` being directed to the built-in Django admin or is that yours?  Either way, somehow people are going to `/admin/login/admin/` and getting redirected to the login screen due to not being authenticated (or possibly not having the right permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Well, struggling for days just to understand it's heroku backend issue and there's not enough information that could help me solving it (i did try to contact heroku support directly but I'm on a free account).

Finally I decided to deploy it using elastic beanstalk. The implementation took some time with long learning curve but now my site works and works great!

Thanks for trying to help Tim.

Cheers!